# CRA development server stop seeing changes in files

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, eslint

I'm having some problems with create-react-app development server (npm/yarn start script). It's stops updating the current errors/warning state, even if I fix them or modify the file. I never had this problem in the last years working with it.

As an example, my current terminal output is:

```
Compiled with warnings.

src/components/CartList.js
  Line 3:15:  'Divider' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

src/providers/User.js
  Line 16:17:  'setToken' is assigned a value but never used  no-unused-vars

Search for the keywords to learn more about each warning.
To ignore, add // eslint-disable-next-line to the line before.
```

But if I modify these files, nothing change on output. I've tried to restart development server, use yarn instead of npm, open development server on different terminals, increase the number of max file watchers...

The only thing that (temporary) fixed it was to stop development server, delete **.eslintcache** file, then restart development server.

Current packages and scripts:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2",
  "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
  "clsx": "^1.1.1",
  "comlink": "^4.3.0",
  "cra-template": "1.0.3",
  "react": "^16.14.0",
  "react-app-rewired": "^2.1.8",
  "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "4.0.1",
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  "worker-loader": "^3.0.6"
},
"scripts": {
  "start": "react-app-rewired start",
  "build": "react-app-rewired build",
  "test": "react-app-rewired test",
  "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"config-overrides-path": "src/react-app-rewired.config.js",
"eslintConfig": {
  "extends": "react-app"
}
```

Hope someone can help me... Thanks!

@EDIT
Using Debian Buster, NPM 6.14.9, Node 14.15.3

Comment: I'm used to restart dev server from time to time to get it to work again...  but might be useful to mention your OS in this question

Comment: I've added my OS, npm and node version

Comment: Apparently, there's [a github issue](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10161) for that